# MenuLibre unable to find menu prefix

Tags: lxde, menulibre

I would like to be able to customize my LXDE menu using MenuLibre, but it seems the only way I'm aloud to edit anything (due to permissions issues) in it is if I run it through the command line with the prefix `sudo`. But whenever I run it this way any new menu directories I add are destroyed upon exiting (even though I keep pressing the save button) and any launchers in this new directory are placed into the `Others` directory. I have also been receiving these errors from the terminal in which I run `sudo menulibre`:

```
** (menulibre:8087): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LntO6MgVTw: Connection refused
No menu prefix found, MenuLibre will not function properly.

(menulibre:8087): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/fusion809/.config/ibus/bus is not root!

WARNING:menulibre: getDefaultMenuPrefix() 'No menu prefix found, MenuLibre will not function properly.'
```

If relevant I am running on 32 bit 15.04.